# Is it supported by the 802.3 Standard to be able to use (1) 1000BASE-T to (2) 100BASE-T and vice versa with a single MAC/PHY?

Tags: ethernet

I am in embedded development and so the question isn't regarding connectors, as we do not use RJ45s, but rather we use custom connectors of aerospace-grade.

Is it possible, and is it typically supported, to take a 1000BASE-T output (non-host interface) and split this to two different 100BASE-T outputs to two different network devices (e.g., so one ethernet interface becomes two from the kernel perspective in Linux).

Is this something conventionally supported by the 802.3 standard?  Note these would be two entirely different network devices it would be connected to.

Then, in some cases based on the wiring configuration instead of two different 100BASE-T, it might just be a single 1000BASE-T to a single network device where high-speed is desired at the loss of an Ethernet interface.

Comment: Not confident enough to post this as an answer but 802.3 doesn't exclude the use of the unused twisted pairs for another purpose. There are definitely splitters available to run two ethernet links over a single cable but they must be used on both ends of the cable. I am almost certain that you have to use two physical interfaces behind your custom connector since a normal ethernet interface would not be required to do anything with the unused wires when in 100BASE-T mode. Maybe a custom driver with the right hardware could get it done.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HW Recs! In general, our site is designed to provide **purchase recommendations** for hardware rather than **technical details or support**.